# A basic doubt on the vector space of complex numbers over field set reals

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a complex vector space. Let $V_\Bbb R$ denote the same vector space, but considered over $\Bbb R$. Is $(V_\Bbb R)_\Bbb C$ same as $\Bbb C$.

I have not understood the question. Although we change the field set the main set of vectors remain the same. Then what is the meaning of it ?

Comment: Have you any familiarity with the tensor product?

Comment: @rghthndsd: no. Can you please explain what has been asked here ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be any real vector space, let $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. Then we define $V_\mathbb{C}$ to be the *abstract* set $$\{\lambda_1e_1 + \dots + \lambda_ne_n : \lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}\}$$
"Abstract" here means that we treat these as formal symbols. It matters not where they come from. In your case, you forget that $1$ and $i$ are complex numbers and treat them as vectors.

We define addition component-wise:
$$(\lambda_1e_1 + \dots + \lambda_ne_n) + (\lambda_1'e_1 + \dots + \lambda_n'e_n) = (\lambda_1+\lambda_1')e_1 + \dots + (\lambda_n+\lambda_n')e_n$$
and we define scalar multiplication:
$$\lambda \cdot (\lambda_1e_1 + \dots + \lambda_ne_n) = \lambda\lambda_1e_1 + \dots + \lambda\lambda_ne_n$$

One may check this is a vector space, and that it has a $\mathbb{C}$-basis $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$

Comment: Yes, when I view $\Bbb C$ as a real vector space $1$ and $i$ are linearly independent, but when we see $\Bbb C$ as a complex vector space then they are dependent. But, I did not understand the notation $(V_\Bbb R)_\Bbb C$.

Comment: "did not", does this mean my answer (the first paragraph) helped? Or do you still not understand?

Comment: why are you saying that $e_1$ and $e_2$ are still linearly independent ? The example in my previous comment shows that this does not hold.

Comment: This is part of the definition. I will edit my answer to be more in depth.